# Azure Data Factory : copying data from CosmosDB to SQL Database fails with "range-indexed" error

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-factory

I need to move data from Azure CosmosDB (previously known as DocumentDB) into Azure SQL database.

I am using the "Copy Data" resource where I have setup the source and the destination as well as the mapping.

The schedule has been setup for once every hour. The issues :

1. I am noticing that the no. of instances or "runs" are more than once per hour. Is this because it is failing and it keeps retrying for a certain amount of times ?
2. The main error why its failing seems to be this :

> Activity Copy_dbo_SubscriptionLocator failed: Failure happened on
>   'Source' side.
>   ErrorCode=UserErrorDocumentDBReadError,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=DocumentDb
>   operation failed: Message: {"Errors":["An invalid query has been
>   specified with filters against path(s) that are not range-indexed.
>   Consider adding allow scan header in the request."]}

What changes do I need to make on CosmosDB end to avoid the error ?

Following is my current indexing policy :

```
{
    "indexingMode": "consistent",
    "automatic": true,
    "includedPaths": [
        {
            "path": "/*",
            "indexes": [
                {
                    "kind": "Range",
                    "dataType": "Number",
                    "precision": -1
                },
                {
                    "kind": "Hash",
                    "dataType": "String",
                    "precision": 3
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "excludedPaths": [
        {
            "path": "/OneOfTheColumns/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Looks like the issue is with the datetime field which needs to be range indexed as a string. I could possibly use the _ts field in the document. But how do I change the Copy job to convert the query's datetime to epoch time and use its value for _ts field.

Comment: Any updates now?Does my answer helps you?

Comment: Haven't made the changes yet. I will follow up after testing.

Comment: Sure! waiting for your reply.

Comment: updated with my current indexing policy ... note the range

Comment: So, still crashed into the same error?

Comment: Any progress now?

Comment: separate question asked here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49164744/azure-data-factory-querying-ts-epoch-field-in-cosmosdb-source

Comment: ok, I'll check the new question. however, i just wonder if this question has be sloved already. If so, you could mark it to end it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about which language you are using, so I reproduced your issue on my side, please refer to my steps.

My sample documents:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Jay",
        "course": "A",
        "score": 50
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Peter",
        "course": "B",
        "score": 20
    }
]
```

Index policy:

```
{
    "indexingMode": "consistent",
    "automatic": true,
    "includedPaths": [
        {
            "path": "/name/?",
            "indexes": [
                {
                    "kind": "Hash",
                    "dataType": "String",
                    "precision": 3
                },
                {
                    "kind": "Range",
                    "dataType": "Number",
                    "precision": -1
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "excludedPaths": [
        {
            "path": "/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Query in the source:`(SELECT c.id,c.name,c.course,c.score FROM c where c.score>30)`

[image]

Reproduce your issue:

[image]

> Range supports efficient equality queries, range queries (using >, <,
>
> > =, <=, !=), and ORDER BY queries. ORDER By queries by default also require maximum index precision (-1). The data type can be String or
> >     Number.

When your have range query, you need define range index on the field. Please refer to official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/indexing-policies#index-data-types-kinds-and-precisions).

So, I modified the above index policy and copied data successfully:

```
{
    "indexingMode": "consistent",
    "automatic": true,
    "includedPaths": [
        {
            "path": "/*",
            "indexes": [
                {
                    "kind": "Range",
                    "dataType": "Number",
                    "precision": -1
                },
                {
                    "kind": "Range",
                    "dataType": "String",
                    "precision": -1
                },
                {
                    "kind": "Spatial",
                    "dataType": "Point"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "excludedPaths": []
}
```

[image]

[image]

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Great details. That was very helpful. In my case, I was querying on datetime in CosmosDB. I had to add a range index on string for that datetime field.

Answer (score 2):

You need to update your index policy of the document collection to allow this query.

Say you have a query like "select * from c where c.property>"something", this c.property must have a range index.

You can learn more about the indexing policy [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/update-your-documentdb-indexing-policies-online/): and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/indexing-policies#modify-the-indexing-policy-of-a-collection)