# Azure Data Factory : querying _ts (epoch) field in CosmosDB source

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, datetime-format, epoch, azure-data-factory

I am trying to copy data from Azure CosmosDB into Azure SQL Database.

In the Azure CosmosDB source, the query is as follows :

```
select * from c where c.DefinitionTime >= '@{formatDateTime(pipeline().parameters.windowStart, 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ' )}' AND c.DefinitionTime < '@{formatDateTime(pipeline().parameters.windowEnd, 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ' )}'
```

In CosmosDB, "DefinitionTime" is stored as a string. To the run the above query, I have to update "DefinitionTime" with range-indexing which is one possible solution.

Another possible solution to is to use the _ts field which is available on all CosmosDB documents. _ts represents when the document was created or last updated in **epoch time**.

So basically the question is how to convert `pipeline().parameters.windowStart` to epoch time. The "formatDateTime" function's second parameter that takes in format doesn't seem to have a way of asking for epoch format. Additionally, there is no way of doing datetime arithmetic to convert to epoch manually.

[image]

Comment: IMO, as there is no built-in support for conversion of epoch to Datetime, having the range index against "DefinitionTime" will be the cleanest solution.